# Antrisymmetrized product of matrices

Tags: matrix, summation, permutation

Let $X_{1},...,X_{N}$ be $N$ matrices. I want to compute an antisymmetrized product of $X_{i}$'s in mathematica:

$X_{[a_{1}...a_{N}]} \equiv \tfrac{1}{N!}\sum_{\sigma}(-1)^{P}X_{\sigma(a_{1})}X_{\sigma(a_{2})}...X_{\sigma(a_{N})},$

where the sum is taken over permutations and the sign factor $(-1)^P$ is $+1$ for even permutations and $-1$ for odd ones.

Eventually, I want to calculate the above equation componentwise by substituting e.g. Dirac $\gamma$-matrices into $X_{i}$'s. How can I make a code for that? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume that the symbol `x` is reserved for the matrices you're planning to use, and the individual matrices are named `x[i]`, then you can do this:

```
xProduct[indices__] := 
 Signature[{indices}] Dot @@ x /@ {indices}

xPerm[a_List] := Total[xProduct @@@ Permutations[a]]

xPerm[{3, 4, 5}]

(*
==> x[3].x[4].x[5] - x[3].x[5].x[4] - x[4].x[3].x[5] + 
 x[4].x[5].x[3] + x[5].x[3].x[4] - x[5].x[4].x[3]
*)
```

Here, `{indices}` is a particular permutation of the provided indices, and the terms in the sum get the correct sign from `Signature`. However, this assumes that the indices that you provide as arguments to the function `xPerm` are in canonical order. If you're not assuming that, the function `xPerm` should be multiplied by `Signature[a]`.